# Removing element from a list at specific index which change with every iteration?

Tags: python-3.6

How to remove element from a list in python have at specific index which change with each iteration ?

Length of input *x* is 5 and *key/index* is 8.

The list should iterate till count is 8, and then the current element is to be removed. This step should be followed till only one element is left.

```
def fl(k):
flag = 0
count = 0
x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
while(count<=k):
    i = flag
    while(i<5):
        count +=1
        if(count==8):
            flag = i
            x.pop(flag)
            count = 0
            if(len(x)==1):
                re(x)
            else:
                print(" ")
        else:
            print(" ")
    i = i + 1
key = 8
fl(8)
```

Output

```
a,b,c,d,e 
a,b,d,e 
a,d,e 
a,d
```

Result will be

```
a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
def fl(k):
    x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
    count = 0
    while x:
        for i in range(len(x)):       #Iterate each index in x
            count += 1                #Increment count
            if count == k:            #Check if count == k
                val = x.pop(i)        #use list.pop to get the deleted item
                count = 0             #reset counter
                break
    return val

print(fl(8))    #--> a
```